# Using grid files (*.gsb) in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, ntv2-transformation, gridfile

When opening a data source in EPSG:25832 in a project with crs set to EPSG:31468 I am prompted to select a datum transformation (e.g. `+nadgrids=BETA2007.gsb`)

[image]

The nationwide standardized grid file for the transformation of geotopography data BeTA2007 is already available and though implemented in QGIS.

By January 2019 the Freistaat Bayern / Germany switches coordinate reference system from EPSG:31468 to EPSG:25832 and for this purpose is going to provide an NTv2 grid file *"BY-KanU"* ("Bayern-Kataster nach UTM"). Various grid files are available in advance: https://www.ldbv.bayern.de/vermessung/utm_umstellung/trans_geofach.html from where I obtained a grid file `BY-KanU_Mittelfranken_Testdatei_vorlaeufig.gsb`

How do I use these grid files in QGIS (applies for 2 and 3 as well)?

Under `Settings | Options... | CRS` it seems that I can define my own transformations, but I do not know how and where to select the desired grid file.

[image]

Comment: Did you put a copy of the new .gsb files in the appropriate folder? Like with OsGeo4W on Windows for example "\osgeo4w\share\proj".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To add a new transformation you need to copy the .gsb file into the appropriate folder. For example "C:\osgeo4w\share\proj". In other QGIS installations it is within the Program folder, but always in the same subfolder (or search for .gsb files in the QGIS folder).

You then need to tell qgis to use the new transformation. Therefore you need to add a value in the srs.db of QGIS (C:\OSGeo4W\apps\qgis\resources\srs.db or equivalent). You need to open the SQLite file with DB Browser for SQLite for example. QGIS itself does not work with this SQLite file as it handles a column the wrong way where you can´t enter text but only numbers and you need to add the filename of the .gsb.

You open the table tbl_datum_transform and add a new line or duplicate the existing one with source=4314 and target=4258 (screenshot 1).

Afterwards you are able to select this transformation in QGIS (screenshot 2).

[image]

[image]

Comment: What's 4314 and 4258 code? I was expecting 31468 and 25832 .

Comment: These are id's referring to the crs stored in a special table in the database mentioned above, not the crses epsg codes.

Answer (score 6):

Since within our IT environment I have no permission to install tools like DB Browser fro SQLite, I tried reproducing the whole with QGIS DB Manager (QGIS 2 + 3) and succeeded!

First I create a new Spatialite connection to the aforementioned `srs.db` (connecting fails, because it of course has no spatialite extension). Then selecting this connection in QGIS DB Manager and firing this SQL statement works:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_datum_transform VALUES (99999, 100099, 4314, 4258, 9615, 'kanu_ntv2_mittelfranken.gsb', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 'Für ALKIS Bayern, amtliche Gitterdatei des LDBV', 'Für Genauigkeitsanforderungen im cm Bereich', 1, 0, NULL)
```

Note that QGIS does not need a restart for the changes to take effect.

[image]

[image]