# Use NTv2 grid files in PostGIS ST_Transform

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, postgresql, gridfile

This question is related to [How to use gridfiles (*.gsb) in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298011/how-to-use-gridfiles-gsb-in-qgis)

Situation is the following: The nationwide standardized gridfile for the transformation of geotopography data BeTA2007 is long since available and I think (but don't know exactly) is used by PostGIS `ST_Transform` when doing a transformation from EPSG:31468 (DHDN GK4 BY) to EPSG:25832 (ETRS89/UTM 32N) and vice versa.

By jan, 2019 the Freistaat Bayern / Germany switched coordinate reference system from EPSG:31468 to EPSG:25832 and for this purpose is going to provide an NTv2 gridfile "BY-KanU" („Bayern-Kataster nach UTM“). Various gridfiles are available: https://www.ldbv.bayern.de/vermessung/utm_umstellung/trans_geofach.html from where I obtained a gridfile `ntv2_bayern.gsb`.

I found a variety of descriptions of how to use these grd-files in QGIS, FME, GeoServer,... but the question is, how to make PostGIS `ST_Transform`use these gridfiles?

Comment: I think you would add the *.gsb* to your systems `PROJ_LIB` directory and refer to it as the `+nadgrids` parameter in a custom *proj4text* in `ST_Transform`. the *proj* library should accept added grid files. can't test to answer right now...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Okay, I had a minute to test (on Linux):

- copy the *.gsb* to the directory defined by `PROJ_LIB`

  - Linux default is `/usr/share/proj/`
  - Windows defaults either to `C:/PROJ/NAD/` or `PROJ_LIB` path (environment variable)
    *I'm not sure here, since those are the paths given for the library if installed standalone; you need to find the directory that will be adressed by the PostGIS installation. Feel free to edit this!)*
- restart *PostgreSQL* server to reload *proj4* setup
- used altered *proj4* string with `ST_Transform(<geom>, <from_proj>, <to_proj>)`, e.g.:
  `'+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=12 +k=1 +x_0=4500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +nadgrids=kanu_ntv2_mittelfranken.gsb +units=m +no_defs '`

---

Validation using only the *Mittelfranken* grid file and one corresponding point from the *Testpunkte* file:

```
SELECT  ST_AsText(
          ST_Transform(
            ST_SetSRID('POINT(4409777.75 5473436.53)'::GEOMETRY, 5678),
            25832
          )
        ) AS not_corrected,
        ST_AsText(
          ST_Transform(
            'POINT(4409777.75 5473436.53)'::GEOMETRY,
            '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=12 +k=1 +x_0=4500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +nadgrids=kanu_ntv2_mittelfranken.gsb +units=m +no_defs ',
            '+proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs '
          )
        ) AS corrected;


              not_corrected               |                corrected                 
------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------
 POINT(627407.217965213 5472427.34870058) | POINT(627407.331497687 5472427.69193261)
```

---

Since both (only axis-inverted) CRS (EPSG:5678 & EPSG:25832) specify either a `+towgs84` parameter (from *epsg.io*) or none (in the `spatial_ref_sys` table), you cannot easily alter the *proj4* string with a `+nadgrids` list; if you'd be using the same CRS on areas outside of the grid files bounds, they'd be distorted.

You can, however, create a custom CRS with the altered *proj4* string and use that as your localized data's CRS (using e.g. `MAX(srid) + 1` as `srid`):

```
INSERT INTO spatial_ref_sys(srid, proj4text)
  VALUES(900914, '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=12 +k=1 +x_0=4500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +nadgrids=kanu_ntv2_mittelfranken.gsb +units=m +no_defs ');


SELECT  ST_AsText(
          ST_Transform(
            ST_SetSRID('POINT(4409777.75 5473436.53)'::GEOMETRY, 5678),
            25832
          )
        ) AS not_corrected,
        ST_AsText(
          ST_Transform(
            ST_SetSRID('POINT(4409777.75 5473436.53)'::GEOMETRY, 900914),
            25832
          )
        ) AS corrected;


              not_corrected               |                corrected                 
------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------
 POINT(627407.217965213 5472427.34870058) | POINT(627407.331497687 5472427.69193261)
```

Comment: Great, worth a beer if we should meet irl :-) I have no such environment variable, but my path (PostgrSQL Install from EnterpriseDB, PostGIS with Application Stack Builder on Win Server 2008 R2) is `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\share\contrib\postgis-2.3\proj`

Comment: I'm trying to do the same (with the path being `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\share\contrib\postgis-3.0\proj`) but it comes up with "ERROR: failed to load datum shift file (-38)"