# Using OSTN15 in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, proj, ntv2-transformation, postgis-3.0

I'm trying to use the OSTN15 transformation to convert ETRS (EPSG:4258) to OSGB (EPSG:27700).

I have downloaded the [NTv2 data from the OS website](https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/documents/resources/OSTN15-NTv2.zip) and extracted into the proj data directory. I have tried a couple of different proj4text values and none give the expected results.

Using the input point `51.40078220140, -3.55128349240` from the User Guide, the correct result should be `292184.87 168003.47 ±0.01`.

```sql
SELECT st_astext(st_transform('SRID=4258;POINT(-3.55128349240 51.40078220140)', 27700));
```

The builtin 27700 uses this one:
`+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs`
Result: `292183.85 168003.44`

Just adding +nadgrids to that and it's completely wrong:
`+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs +nadgrids=@OSTN15_NTv2_ETRStoOSGB.gsb`
Result: `292100.78 168057.91`

Based on [this blog post](http://blog.mackerron.com/2012/07/03/ostn02-for-postgis/) I tried this and it gives the same result:
`+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +units=m +no_defs +nadgrids=@OSTN15_NTv2_ETRStoOSGB.gsb`
Result: `292100.78 168057.91`

I'm afraid I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. Are additional parameters or changes needed to the proj instructions, or have I missed something elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a Windows problem, as on Linux there is no trouble.

With [OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS.gsb](https://github.com/OSGeo/proj-datumgrid/raw/master/europe/OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS.gsb) in the `/usr/share/proj` directory, after restarting the service it works:

```sql
SELECT st_astext(st_transform('SRID=4258;POINT(-3.55128349240 51.40078220140)', 27700));

-- POINT(292184.870542716 168003.465539408)
```

Upgrading to PostGIS 3.2 includes PROJ 9, then you can more easily update the PROJ data files:

```sh
sudo projsync --system-directory --source-id uk_os
```

Answer (score 4):

Given the `from_proj` and `to_proj` strings as parameters, `ST_Transform`s *proj4* core (on Linux) uses the *inverse* transformation of the **OSGB to ETRS** grid correctly **when projecting from ETRS to OSGB**

```
SELECT  ST_AsText(
            ST_Transform(
                'POINT(-3.55128349240 51.40078220140)',
                '+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs',
                '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +nadgrids=@OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS.gsb +units=m +no_defs'
            )
        )
;

                st_astext                 
------------------------------------------
 POINT(292184.870542716 168003.465539408)     -- Test point: 292184.870 168003.465
```

while it uses the **correct transformation direction rules** for a projection **from OSGB to ETRS**

```
SELECT  ST_AsText(
            ST_Transform(
                'POINT(422242.186 433818.701)',
                '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +datum=OSGB36 +nadgrids=@OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS.gsb +units=m +no_defs',
                '+proj=longlat +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +no_defs'
            )
        )
;

                 st_astext                 
-------------------------------------------
 POINT(-1.66379169549632 53.8002151871972)    -- Test point: -1.66379168242 53.80021519630
```

Note the **same grid file** in both `proj4` strings.

---

Follow the instructions in my [other answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/310613/93656) you commented on to add respective entries to the `spatial_ref_sys` table.

Comment: As to _why_ it does this I am not 100% sure yet. Needs more investigation...

Comment: I do not get that result. Your first query returns `POINT(292100.782330781 168057.913383984)`

Comment: I tried again on a Linux installation, and then OSGBtoETRS works. Looks like the Windows PostGIS comes with an older proj (5.2.0 vs 6.3.1).

Comment: I tried the latest Windows PostGIS, with proj 7.1.1, and it made no difference. I guess something just isn't ported correctly.

Comment: In fact, it appears that the default 27700 already works correctly in the Linux version, returning exactly the same value as the nadgrids, at least for this test point.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I discovered that I was working on a remote database but I was saving the .gsb files from OS in my local version of proj.

When I run the query of the remote db I get the wrong answer:

```
remotedb=> select st_astext(St_Transform(st_Setsrid(st_point(-3.55128349240,51.40078220140),4258),
'+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +nadgrids=@OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS.gsb +units=m +no_defs'::text));                 
------------------------------------------
 POINT(292100.782330781 168057.913383984)
(1 row)
```

If I simply connect to my local postgres (by running psql on the terminal) it works:

```
    localdb=# select st_astext(St_Transform(st_Setsrid(st_point(-3.55128349240,51.40078220140),4258),
'+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +nadgrids=@OSTN15_NTv2_OSGBtoETRS.gsb +units=m +no_defs'::text));                
------------------------------------------
POINT(292184.870548388 168003.465444948)
    (1 row)
```

I hope this helps.