# How to use gridfiles (*.gsb) in QGIS 3.10.0-2

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, gridfile

It seems that the solution previously given does not work anymore:

[How to use gridfiles (*.gsb) in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298011/how-to-use-gridfiles-gsb-in-qgis)

Does someone know how to add new transformations in using gridfiles *.gsb in QGIS 3.10?

Comment: Maybe this problem is related to that bug https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/32795 ?

Comment: After some investigations, it seems that QGIS 3.10.0-2 is only using the transformations saved in "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\share\proj\proj.db" and does not take into account what is in "C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\qgis\resources\srs.db"

The question is then : how to add a new database or how to modify the one used by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this bug is fixed with the new version Qgis 3.10.2.

In the CRS menu in the "Default Datum Transformations" I got a suggestion to download the transfornation grid I needed (proj-datumgrid-europe-1.5) here => https://download.osgeo.org/proj/?C=M&O=D

Then I unzipped the file to the right directory (C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\share\proj). This directory could be located under C:\OSGeo4W64\share\proj, depending on how you installed Qgis on your PC.

After a restart of Qgis, it worked!