# QGIS transformation defined in srs.db tbl_datum_transform table not available in Select Datum Transformations dialog

Tags: coordinate-system, qgis-3, ntv2-transformation, gridfile

This question ist related to this post: [How to use gridfiles (*.gsb) in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298011/how-to-use-gridfiles-gsb-in-qgis)

We have integrated our gridfile according to the answers in the referred post, and in some previous version of QGIS 3 it worked fine (I don't know exactly which one, but I presume something around 3.4).

Entry in `tbl_datum_transform` in `srs.db`:

[image]

Related gridfile `kanu_ntv2_mittelfranken.gsb`is under `OSGeo4W/share/proj`:

[image]

But now (QGIS 3.10.x LTR) the transformation defined in the `tbl_datum_transform` is not available in the ***Select Datum Transform*** dialog (**Note** the **Remarks** for the selected Transformation):

[image]

What seems totally weird to me is, that the only record in the `tbl_datum_transform` table with a remark beginning with '*Developed for ATKIS...*' is referring our `kanu_ntv2_mittelfranken.gsb` and **NOT** BETA2007.gsb as in the screenshot.

I wonder if the location for the `srs.db` has changed meanwhile, but I couldn't find another.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We just found that everything seems to have moved to `...\OSGeo4W64\share\proj\proj.db`, this is where environment variable `PROJ_LIB` points to:

[image]

The table where the important information resides is `grid_transformation`, whichs attributes are basically self-explanatory:

[image]

Here is some sql that adds the transformation to the table (Thanks to @pascatl):

```
INSERT INTO grid_transformation (
auth_name, 
code, 
name, 
description, 
scope, 
method_auth_name, 
method_code, 
method_name, 
source_crs_auth_name, 
source_crs_code, 
target_crs_auth_name, 
target_crs_code, 
area_of_use_auth_name, 
area_of_use_code, 
accuracy, 
grid_param_auth_name, 
grid_param_code, 
grid_param_name, 
grid_name, 
grid2_param_auth_name, 
grid2_param_code,
grid2_param_code, 
grid2_param_name, 
grid2_name, 
interpolation_crs_auth_name, 
interpolation_crs_code, 
operation_version, 
deprecated)
SELECT
auth_name, 
99999, 
'DHDN to ETR89 (kanu_ntv2_mittelfranken)', 
'Transformation mit Gitterdatei kanu_ntv2_mittelfranken vom LDBV Bayern', 
'Für Genauigkeiten im Zentimeterbereich', 
method_auth_name, 
method_code, 
method_name, 
source_crs_auth_name, 
source_crs_code, 
target_crs_auth_name, 
target_crs_code, 
area_of_use_auth_name, 
area_of_use_code, 
0.1, 
grid_param_auth_name, 
grid_param_code, 
grid_param_name, 
'kanu_ntv2_mittelfranken.gsb', 
grid2_param_auth_name, 
grid2_param_code, 
grid2_param_code, 
grid2_param_name, 
grid2_name, 
interpolation_crs_auth_name, 
interpolation_crs_code, 
operation_version, 
deprecated
FROM grid_transformation 
WHERE code = 15948
```

Now we have the transformation available (restart may be required):

[image]