# Transformation not available in QGIS despite adding it to proj.db and adding GSB file to proj folder

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

In QGIS v3.10, I am trying to add a transformation from NAD83 (EPSG:2958) and NAD83 CSRS (EPSG:26917) for Ontario, Canada, using the GSB file from [here](https://search.open.canada.ca/en/sd/id/b6156aee-3c7e-475f-b3fa-35fe38b2046e).

1. I have added my grid transformation file here: `C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\share\proj\ON83CSv1.gsb`
   (after reading [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/375619/qgis-transformation-defined-in-srs-db-tbl-datum-transform-table-not-available-in))
2. I addded an entry to `C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\share\proj\proj.db:grid_transformation`.
3. When I go to `Settings>Options>Default Datum Transformations`, and select From EPSG:2958 to EPSG:26917, I do not see the transformation that I added.
4. I believe I am adding the entry to the correct table, because when I edit another entry in this table for an existing transformation, I see my edit within the QGIS GUI.

Does anyone know:

- Why I am not seeing my transformation in QGIS despite it being in the database (do I need to edit other tables?)
- Is there an easier way to add a transformation with a GSB file in QGIS?