# Using NTv2 gridfiles in QGIS >= 3.22.x LTR with proj 9.x

Tags: qgis, proj, ntv2-transformation, gridfile

This question is a follow-up to [QGIS transformation defined in srs.db tbl_datum_transform table not available in Select Datum Transformations dialog](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/375619/qgis-transformation-defined-in-srs-db-tbl-datum-transform-table-not-available-in)

Basically it is all about making an NTv2 gridfile (*.gsb) for transforming EPSG:31468 to EPSG:25832 (and vice versa) available in QGIS (gridfile obtained from https://geodaten.bayern.de/oadownload/bvv_internet/kanu/kanu_ntv2_mittelfranken.zip ~100Mb).

When we use the approach from the referred thread, the transformation is not available in Select Datum Transformations dialog (see below). We observe this since QGIS 3.22.x LTR with proj 9.1.1, the approach worked well until QGIS 3.16.x LTR with proj 6.3.2.

It may not be the key point, but worth a note that some attributes have changed in the `grid_transformation` table in the `proj.db` database, so the following `INSERT`s work:

```
INSERT INTO grid_alternatives VALUES ('kanu_ntv2_mittelfranken.gsb', '', 'kanu_ntv2_mittelfranken.gsb', 'NTv2', 'hgridshift', 1, NULL, '', 0, 1, NULL)

INSERT INTO grid_transformation (
auth_name, 
code, 
name, 
description, 
--scope, 
method_auth_name, 
method_code, 
method_name, 
source_crs_auth_name, 
source_crs_code, 
target_crs_auth_name, 
target_crs_code, 
--area_of_use_auth_name, 
--area_of_use_code, 
accuracy, 
grid_param_auth_name, 
grid_param_code, 
grid_param_name, 
grid_name, 
grid2_param_auth_name, 
grid2_param_code,
grid2_param_code, 
grid2_param_name, 
grid2_name, 
interpolation_crs_auth_name, 
interpolation_crs_code, 
operation_version, 
deprecated)

SELECT
auth_name, 
99999, 
'DHDN to ETR89 (kanu_ntv2_mittelfranken)', 
'Transformation mit Gitterdatei kanu_ntv2_mittelfranken vom LDBV Bayern', 
--'Für Genauigkeiten im Zentimeterbereich', 
method_auth_name, 
method_code, 
method_name, 
source_crs_auth_name, 
source_crs_code, 
target_crs_auth_name, 
target_crs_code, 
--area_of_use_auth_name, 
--area_of_use_code, 
0.1, 
grid_param_auth_name, 
grid_param_code, 
grid_param_name, 
'kanu_ntv2_mittelfranken.gsb', 
grid2_param_auth_name, 
grid2_param_code, 
grid2_param_code, 
grid2_param_name, 
grid2_name, 
interpolation_crs_auth_name, 
interpolation_crs_code, 
operation_version, 
deprecated

FROM grid_transformation 
WHERE code = 15948
```

With this and similar statements, we generate the following rows in `grid_transformation`...

[image]

(note the various combinations of `gridfile`, `source_crs_code` and `target_crs_code`)

... as well as an entry in `grid_alternatives` (of which we do not know if it is really necessary):

[image]

But the grid transformation is not available in QGIS:

[image]

So since we found the whole thing very, very poorly (or not at all...) documented (cp. https://proj.org/resource_files.html#proj-db): **What are we missing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following works for me (downloads all the BY-KanU grids, converts them to tif and adds them to the user's proj.db):

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

exec 3< <(projinfo --searchpaths | sed -e 's#\\#/#g' -e 's#\r##' | head -2)
read U <&3
read D <&3

[ -f $U/proj.db ] || { mkdir -p $U; cp $D/proj.db $U/proj.db; }

curl -k -C - -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OSGeo/PROJ-data/master/grid_tools/ntv2_to_gtiff.py
curl -k -C - -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OSGeo/PROJ-data/master/grid_tools/cloud_optimize_gtiff.py

for i in \
        kanu_ntv2_schwaben \
        kanu_ntv2_oberfranken \
        kanu_ntv2_mittelfranken \
        kanu_ntv2_unterfranken \
        kanu_ntv2_oberpfalz \
        kanu_ntv2_oberbayern \
        kanu_ntv2_niederbayern \
        ntv2_bayern
do
        curl -k -C - -O https://geodaten.bayern.de/oadownload/bvv_internet/kanu/$i.zip

        unzip $i.zip

        n=${i##*_}
        t="BY-KanU ${n^}"

        python3 ntv2_to_gtiff.py \
                --copyright "Derived from work by LBDV. Data license Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Namensnennung-Keine Bearbeitung 3.0 Unported (CC BY-ND 3.0): https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/3.0/deed.de" \
                --source-crs EPSG:4314 \
                --target-crs EPSG:4258 \
                --datetime NONE \
                --description "$t" \
                --do-not-write-accuracy-samples \
                $i.gsb \
                $U/de_by_kanu_$n.tif

        sqlite3 $U/proj.db <<EOF
INSERT INTO "grid_transformation"(auth_name,code,name,description,method_auth_name,method_code,method_name,source_crs_auth_name,source_crs_code,target_crs_auth_name,target_crs_code,accuracy,grid_param_auth_name,grid_param_code,grid_param_name,grid_name,grid2_param_auth_name,grid2_param_code,grid2_param_name,grid2_name,interpolation_crs_auth_name,interpolation_crs_code,operation_version,deprecated) VALUES (
  /*                   auth_name = */ 'EPSG',
  /*                        code = */ 'DE_BY_${i##*_}',
  /*                        name = */ 'DHDN to ETRS89 (BY)',
  /*                 description = */ '$t',
  /*            method_auth_name = */ 'EPSG',
  /*                 method_code = */ '9615',
  /*                 method_name = */ 'NTv2',
  /*        source_crs_auth_name = */ 'EPSG',
  /*             source_crs_code = */ '4314',
  /*        target_crs_auth_name = */ 'EPSG',
  /*             target_crs_code = */ '4258',
  /*                    accuracy = */ '0.1',
  /*        grid_param_auth_name = */ 'EPSG',
  /*             grid_param_code = */ '8656',
  /*             grid_param_name = */ 'Latitude and longitude difference file',
  /*                   grid_name = */ '$i.gsb',
  /*       grid2_param_auth_name = */ NULL,
  /*            grid2_param_code = */ NULL,
  /*            grid2_param_name = */ NULL,
  /*                  grid2_name = */ NULL,
  /* interpolation_crs_auth_name = */ NULL,
  /*      interpolation_crs_code = */ NULL,
  /*           operation_version = */ NULL,
  /*                  deprecated = */ '0'
);

INSERT INTO "grid_alternatives"(original_grid_name,proj_grid_name,old_proj_grid_name,proj_grid_format,proj_method,inverse_direction,package_name,url,direct_download,open_license,directory) VALUES (
  /* original_grid_name = */ '$i.gsb',
  /*     proj_grid_name = */ 'de_by_kanu_$n.tif',
  /* old_proj_grid_name = */ '$i.gsb',
  /*   proj_grid_format = */ 'GTiff',
  /*        proj_method = */ 'hgridshift',
  /*  inverse_direction = */ '0',
  /*       package_name = */ NULL,
  /*                url = */ NULL,
  /*    direct_download = */ '1',
  /*       open_license = */ '1',
  /*          directory = */ ''
);

INSERT INTO "usage"(auth_name,code,object_table_name,object_auth_name,object_code,extent_auth_name,extent_code,scope_auth_name,scope_code) VALUES (
  /*         auth_name = */ NULL,
  /*              code = */ NULL,
  /* object_table_name = */ 'grid_transformation',
  /*  object_auth_name = */ 'EPSG',
  /*       object_code = */ 'DE_BY_$n',
  /*  extent_auth_name = */ 'EPSG',
  /*       extent_code = */ '3339',
  /*   scope_auth_name = */ 'EPSG',
  /*        scope_code = */ '1041'
);
EOF

        rm $i.gsb
done
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

At least for Proj it seems to be possible to use a workaround and update the existing record

```
UPDATE grid_transformation
set grid_name='kanu_ntv2_mittelfranken.gsb'
WHERE code = 15948;
```

Now projinfo shows that new grid file is recognized (but not found because I did not download the grid file).

```
projinfo -s EPSG:31468 -t EPSG:25832 -o proj

Operation No. 2:

unknown id, Inverse of 3-degree Gauss-Kruger zone 4 + DHDN to ETRS89 (8) + UTM zone 32N, 0.9 m, Germany - onshore - states of Baden-Wurtemberg, Bayern, Berlin, Brandenburg, Bremen, Hamburg, Hessen, Mecklenburg-Vorpommern, Niedersachsen, Nordrhein-Westfalen, Rheinland-Pfalz, Saarland, Sachsen, Sachsen-Anhalt, Schleswig-Holstein, Thuringen., at least one grid missing

PROJ string:
+proj=pipeline
  +step +proj=axisswap +order=2,1
  +step +inv +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=12 +k=1 +x_0=4500000 +y_0=0
        +ellps=bessel
  +step +proj=hgridshift +grids=kanu_ntv2_mittelfranken.gsb
  +step +proj=utm +zone=32 +ellps=GRS80
```

Comment: I think it's `UPDATE grid_transformation...` but despite, your approach makes the gridfile available in QGIS. Yaayyyy! It does not actually exlpain why an exact copy of the `code=15948` row does not make the gridfile available, but this seems an academic question at this point. So for now I think you are on a good way to earn the 200 reputation...

Comment: Thanks, corrected. There must be something extra to take care of when adding new transformations. I made a few unsuccessful tests but it would take more time to reveal the relations between all the involved tables.