# Adding custom on the fly transformation in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, ntv2-transformation, otf

I'm using QGIS version 3.20.0. I need to transform EPSG:4326 into EPSG:31468 on the fly, using the equivalent of ArcGIS's "DHDN To WGS 1984 4 NTv2", i.e. with a NTv2 grid.

I've tested the transformation itself using the custom projection option, method see below**. However, I can't find a way to get this to show up as transformation option (under Project > Properties > Transformations). Do I need additional files/settings?

**

1. Downloaded this: http://crs.bkg.bund.de/crseu/crs/descrtrans/BeTA/BETA2007.gsb
2. Put it here: C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.20.0\share\proj
3. Started QGIS, went to Setting > Custom Projection
4. Created: "WGS84_to_GK4"
5. Using proj string: "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=12 +k=1
   +x_0=4500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=bessel +datum=potsdam +nadgrids=BETA2007.gsb +units=m +no_defs"

Test:

- N: 47.83496215890 = 5300500.0000
- E: 10.66278832300 = 4400000.0000

Comment: Only adding the gsb file in the proj directory is not enough. See answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298011/using-gridfiles-gsb-in-qgis/298027 You may also look at this related discussion http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/how-to-register-gsb-transformation-in-proj-db-td5439332.html